# In camera tracking how do i figure out the settings for the cannon 6d

Tags: camera, tracking

In camera tracking how do i figure out the settings for a cannon 6d. I know the sensor width it 35.8 but I'm unsure about what to use for the other settings. Especially pixel width and optical center.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Optical center** should be the center of your image height/2 , width/2 ,  unless you have cropped the image. Then it should be the original center of your image. There is button for this labeled <kbd>center</kbd>. This is relevant to accounting for lens distortion.  The

**Pixel aspect ratio** should be **one** unless you used something like an anamorphic lens, which stretches the pixels when the image distortion is countered in post.